# Does "Geht los!" mean the same as "Los geht's"? And is "Geht's los!" a wrong use of "'s", i.e. "es"? Why so?

Tags: meaning, translation, word-usage, difference, pronoun

I understand that **Los geht's!** means "It's on!" "Here we go!" (https://qr.ae/pGcQL4).

Does **Geht los!** mean the same as **Los geht's!**?

Is it incorrect to say **Geht's los!**? (i.e. **'s** is not necessary). Why so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You are right with your assumption. `Los geht's!` means indeed something like `Here we go!`. The expression `Geht los!` may mean the same as above in sloppy speech, when you assume that the `Es` is omitted. `Es geht los!` would be correct in this sense.
Literally translated `Geht los!` means imperative plural, meaning `Go on!`. Singular would be `Geh los!`, which seems to be the same in English: `Go on!`.
So it depends a bit on the context.

`Geht's los?` is only valid in a question, meaning `Does it go on?` Maybe in bavarian dialect you may hear this as order, but this should be confirmed by a native bavarian speaker.

Comment: Just a note: *Geht's los?* can also mean: What's wrong with you?

Comment: @Olafant, that's right, I did not think about it.

Comment: @Olafant Not where I live. That would be "Geht's noch?"

Comment: @HaraldLichtenstein Your're right, _gehts_ (or generally the _-ts_ ending of the second person plural) can definitely be an imperative plural in Bavarian dialects, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Bavarian#Verbs. This is **not** related to the enclitic _'s_ < _es_.

Comment: @Roland I know "Geht's noch?' with same meaning. "Geht's los?" is def. used in the north.

Comment: @Olafant Well, I grew up in the North and currently live in Lower Saxony. I've never heard "Geht's los?" in the meaning of "What's wrong with you?" and would certainly not understand it this way. Must be a sociolect.

Comment: @Olafant, I grew up in Hessia, *Geht's los* was never used as *What's wrong with you?*. However: *Ich glaub' es geht los!* indeed is often used in the sense of *I cannot believe it, what is wrong with you?*.